# When is this equality true?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Given two vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, I noticed that
$$\vec{u}\cdot\nabla\vec{v}+\vec{v}\cdot\nabla\vec{u}=\vec v(\nabla\cdot \vec u)+\vec u(\nabla\cdot \vec v)$$
when $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ only have at most one non-zero component along the same standard basis. Is this true any other time?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I think they are both vectors

Comment: $\vec{u}\cdot\nabla$ is a scalar. This is applied to each component of vector $\vec{v}$ which remains a vector

Comment: Right - I overlooked that you were applying this to a vector.